# Add data to specific record in CSV file

Tags: java, csv, file, record

I have a record in a CSV file and i am trying to add some extra info (a name) to the same specific record with the following code but it does not work. There is no error shown but the info i am trying to add just does not appear. What am i missing ?

```
public class AddName {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String filepath="Zoo.csv";
    String editTerm="Fish";
    String addedName="Ron";

    addToRecord(filepath,editTerm,addedName);

}
public static void addToRecord(String filepath,String editTerm,String addedName){

    String animal= "";

    try{
        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(filepath,true);
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(bw);
            if (animal.equals(editTerm)){
                pw.println(editTerm+","+addedName);
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
            }
        System.out.println("Your Record was saved");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Your Record was not saved");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: specific record or specific row, column ?

Comment: i need to add the name to a specific record on the second column, like this:                   | animal1 | name1 | - record 1

Comment: I don't think that you even read your input CSV file, do you? The local variable "animal" is always an empty String, presumably you wanted to read the file first, line by line and if the line is as expected modify it before writing it again?

Comment: Any suggestions with how i should change the code to achieve that please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the requirement is to add an extra column if the animal name matches. It's equivalent to changing a particular line in a file. Here's a simple approach to achieve the same, (Without using any extra libraries),

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class EditLineInFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String animal = "Fish";

        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Zoo.csv");
        try {
            List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(path);
            int counter = 0;
            for (String line : allLines) {
                if (line.equals(animal)) {
                    line += ",Ron";
                    allLines.set(counter, line);
                }
                counter++;
            }
            Files.write(path, allLines);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using a CSV library to help you out with parsing CSVs because it is more complicated than it looks, especially when it comes down to quoting.

Here's a quick example using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net) that clones the original CSV file and adds "Ron" as necessary:

```
public class Csv1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CsvValidationException {
        addToRecord("animal.csv", "animal-new.csv", "fish", "Ron");
    }

    public static void addToRecord(String filepathIn, String filepathOut, String editTerm, String addedName)
            throws IOException, CsvValidationException {

        try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filepathIn))) {
            try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filepathOut))) {

                String[] values;
                while ((values = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                    if (values.length > 2 && values[0].equals(editTerm)) {
                        values[1] = addedName;
                    }
                    writer.writeNext(values);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Given the file:

```
type,name,age
fish,,10
cat,,12
lion,tony,10
```

will produce:

```
"type","name","age"
"fish","Ron","10"
"cat","","12"
"lion","tony","10"
```

(You can look for answers about outputting quotes in the resulting CSV)

Answer (score -1):

You may use this code to replace the file content "Fish" to "Fish, Ron"

```
public static void addToRecord(String filepath, String editTerm, String addedName) {

    try (Stream<String> input = Files.lines(Paths.get(filepath));
         PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("Output.csv", "UTF-8"))
    {
        input.map(s -> s.replaceAll(editTerm, editTerm + "," + addedName))
                .forEachOrdered(output::println);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```